# How should I structure my database?

Tags: sql, database, data-structures, structure

I'm a complete beginner to SQL. I currently have "coders block" and need help pushing forward.

---

I am unsure how I should structure my database. **I've included an image to hopefully give you a better picture of what I am trying to achieve. Please take a look at it**

[image]

---

There will be multiple shops which contain multiple items. Each item will have a buying price and a selling price. An item may be used by multiple shops, and may have a different buying/selling price from other shops. My goal in creating this database is to be able to query an item and determine which shop(s) are buying or selling it at the lowest price.

---

### EDIT:

My idea is to create three tables: Items, Stores, and ItemsStores.

**Stores** will have columns *ID, Name*

**Items** will have columns *ID, Name*

**ItemsStores** will have columns *Store, Item, Buy Price, Sell Price.*

I feel creating a column for just an ID and a name may be redundant. Am I wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

---

I've read a few *[articles](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/database-diagram/database-design)* and even watched *[videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s91pPLx_T3Q)* on the basics of structuring databases, but for some reason it's just not clicking with me. Any help on what my tables / columns should look like would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're asking us for a full schema with explanation, then I'd say your question is too broad.  I would suggest that the backbone of your schema might be a bridge table which stores the relationships between stores and items which they have in stock.  This implies two other tables, as well, one for stores and one for items.  This is a good starting point.

Comment: I should have included my attempted solution for my problem. [ editing and adding it now]

My original solution was to just use one table (stores) consisting of the store name, the item, buying price, selling price. But this would lead to many duplicates of the store name and the items.

I will try creating two tables for items and stores now. I don't know why I did not think of that. The columns will be the ID of the store, and the store name. The columns for the items will be buying and selling price. From here I just need to learn how to relate the two.

Comment: Your relate the two via a _bridge_ table, which just stores keys for a store mapping to keys for one or more items.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I've included my attempt at a bridge table in my original question now. Does this look good? I feel like creating another table for one value (the name of the store) is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start designing a database, you need to think of the question by highlighting the objects that needs a table. The more the merrier (surprise surprise).
So this is how I would write down the problem:
There will be multiple **shops** which contain multiple **items**. Each item will have a **buying price** and a **selling price**. An item may be used by **multiple**   shops, and may have a different buying/selling price from other shops. My goal in creating this database is to be able to query an item and determine which shop(s) are buying or selling it at the lowest price.

multiple is highlighted because that means a many to many relationship

obviously you need to decide (that's the tricky part) where you want the price to be: is price an attribute of item? or of an item in a shop?

Once your head stops spinning and you figure that one out you'll be in a much better position.